# Unable to get value from xpath

Tags: css, xpath

I have below html code from which I want to extract the text "Extracted Text" inside last  tag by using xpath of css selector. the text "value" inside 2nd  tag will always be changing and we have stored that value in some variable. So I want to write a code which will parse below html and extract the text.

```
<div>
    <div>value</div>
    <div class="a">
        <div>
            <div>Extracted Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with below code:

```
response.xpath('//div[div="variable"]//div/div/text()')
```

but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: the class='a' element is not child of the div container value

Answer (score 1):

This xpath does what you want

`'//div[text()="value"]/following-sibling::div/div/div/text()'`

Tested on command line

`xmllint --html --xpath '//div[text()="value"]/following-sibling::div/div/div/text()' test.html
Extracted Text`