# Ansible - get XML element where attribute equals value

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, ansible

I have an xml file with following structure:

```
<nodes>
  <node123>
    <node_type>apic</node_type>
    <example_attribute>blahblah</example_attribute>
    <example_attribute>blahblah</example_attribute>
    ...
  </node123>
  <node789>
    <node_type>NOT-apic</node_type>
    <example_attribute>blah2blah2</example_attribute>
    <example_attribute>blah2blah2</example_attribute>
    ...
  </node789>
  ...
</nodes>
```

My goal is to get a list of nodes (including the node name) with ALL attributes, but only when the type-attribute is equal to "apic".
My Ansible code looks like this and i dont understand why it's not working:

```
- name: get nodes from xml
  xml:
    path: "{{playbook_dir}}/nnmconf_nnm.xml"
    xpath: //*                            # -> I tried following: //, /*, /nodes, nodes
    content: text
  register: nodes

- name: Output only nodes with type apic
  debug:
    msg: "{{item}}"
  #when: "{{item.node_type}} == 'apic'"   # -> not working yet
  loop: "{{nodes}}"                       # -> also tried {{nodes.matches}}
```

Instead of giving me the correct Output it keeps giving me every single line as an element. The output looks like this:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "blablabla matches: [{'nodes': {}}, {'f0000y': {}}, {'node_notes': {}}, {'flag_cw2000': {}}, {'date_added': {}}, {'node_place': {}}, {'node_msggrp': {}}, {'provider_sla': {}}, {'node_status': {}}, {'node_alias': {}}, ...
```

There should be a simple solution for this simple problem, but the xml module from ansible drives me crazy. Please help

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687154/2834978

Answer (score 2):

The closest result for the given data structure, with the Ansible [`xml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/xml_module.html)_module and an [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/?title=xpath) I could get was

```
- name: Get element values from XML
  xml:
    path: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.xml"
    xpath: //nodes/*/*[text() = 'apic']/following-sibling::*
    content: text
  register: result

- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.matches }}"
```

but that did not gave the "node name".

```
TASK [Show result] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - example_attribute: blahblah
  - example_attribute: blahblah
```

Better result would be possible with a slightly changed data structure of the input

```
<nodes>
  <node>
    <value>123</value>
    <node_type>apic</node_type>
    <example_attribute>blah1blah1</example_attribute>
    <example_attribute>blah1blah1</example_attribute>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>456</value>
    <node_type>apic</node_type>
    <example_attribute>blah2blah2</example_attribute>
    <example_attribute>blah2blah2</example_attribute>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>789</value>
    <node_type>NOT-apic</node_type>
    <example_attribute>blah3blah3</example_attribute>
    <example_attribute>blah3blah3</example_attribute>
  </node>
</nodes>
```